# Процедура записи в файл

Tags: delphi

Есть процедура, записывающая данные в файл:

```
PROCEDURE SAVE(X1:REAL;K:STRING;Mstr:INTEGER);
VAR V:STRING;
BEGIN
ASSIGN(F,'SIMPLEX.DAT');
APPEND(F);
CASE Mstr OF
 0:WRITELN(F,'');
 1:BEGIN
   IF K=' ' THEN STR(X1:1:0,V) ELSE STR(X1:10:4,V);
    WRITE(F,V);
    WRITE(F,'  ');
   END;
 2:WRITE(F,K);
 3:WRITELN(F,K);
END;
CLOSE(F);
END;
```

Как нужнопереписать процедуры, чтобы все данные записывались не в файл, а выводились, скажем, в компонент `Edit` (`Edit1.Text:=...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписать нужно так: пройти по всем местам записи в файл и осуществить замену записи в файл на запись в компонент. То есть вместо WRITE(F, ...) проставить edit.Text = ...